# How to access subproperty of IEnumerable in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a `User.cs` model which looks like

```
class User
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a `UsersViewModel.cs`

```
class UsersViewModel
{
    IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
    readonly DatabaseContext database;

    UsersViewModel()
    {
        Users = 
            from user in database.Users
            orderby user.Id
            select user;
    }
}
```

where `DatabaseContext` is a class allows me to talks to my PostgreSQL.

What I want to do is populate a page with `Name` of each `User` present in `IEnumerable<User>`. I have `UsersPage.xaml` which tries to do this with

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding }" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

but it returns me

```
MyGlobalNamespace.Models.User
```

as many times as I have `User` records in my database. I know that trick lies somewhere in `<Label Text="{Binding }" />` yet I can't figure out how to do this.

However, I managed to achieve what I want by adding `List<string> UserNames` which is populated via

```
foreach (var user in Users)
{
    UserNames.Add(user.Name);
}
```

and replacing `{Binding Users}` with `{Binding UserNames}`, but I highly doubt this is the way I'm  supposed to do things

Comment: Try `<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">` and `<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />`.

Comment: dear Lord, I feel so much like an idiot right now. thanks @HamidRezaMohammadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was times easier than I thought. As @HamidRezaMohammadi said `UsersPage.xaml` should look like this:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

where `Name` relies on property in my `User.cs` model